# Running a Voldemort application

Tags: java, voldemort

I've been failing to run a Java application which makes use of Voldemort. I'm trying to run the Client Example which can be found with the Voldemort download.

I compiled the code as follows:`javac -classpath voldemort-0.96.jar ClientExample.java`

No errors appeared. But when I try to run the code as follows:`java -classpath voldemort-0.96.jar ClientExample`

I get the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ClientExample
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ClientExample
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: ClientExample. Program will exit.
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The voldemort jar is in the same folder.

Edit: Here is the ClientExample code

```
package voldemort.examples;

import voldemort.client.ClientConfig;
import voldemort.client.SocketStoreClientFactory;
import voldemort.client.StoreClient;
import voldemort.client.StoreClientFactory;
import voldemort.versioning.Versioned;

public class ClientExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String bootstrapUrl = "tcp://localhost:6666";
    StoreClientFactory factory = new SocketStoreClientFactory(new ClientConfig().setBootstrapUrls(bootstrapUrl));

    StoreClient<String, String> client = factory.getStoreClient("my_store_name");

    Versioned<String> version = client.get("some_key");

    version.setObject("new_value");

    client.put("some_key", version);
}
}
```

Comment: Is ClientExample in the default package or some other package? If the later, you need to include the fully qualified class name (which includes the package) on the command line.

Comment: Sorry, thought I'd just close the topic. You were correct in including the package as well.

Comment: The same issue i am also getting how will fix this issue?